# Fixed header temporarily wider when embedding Instagram posts in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, css-position, embed, instagram-api, mobile-chrome

I noticed a strange behavior with my fixed position header in Chrome on Android when embedding Instagram posts on my page: the fixed header is temporarily resized slightly wider while Instagram's `embeds.js` is processing the page to add the post contents.

The animated gif below shows the effect on a minimalistic page: the right edge of the blue-bordered header momentarily jumps to the right whenever I click the "Show Instagram post" button.

[image: Demo of observed behavior]

You can see the [demo source code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/peruukki/pen/rzxrKe/), but here it is too:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</header>
<button class="show-button">Show Instagram post</button>
<div id="instagram-post"></div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.show-button {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 3rem 0 1rem;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.show-button').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?omitscript=true&url=https://www.instagram.com/p/tsxp1hhQTG',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
      $('#instagram-post').html(response.html);
      instgrm.Embeds.process();
    }
  });  
});
```

jQuery and Instagram's [embeds.js](https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js) are also included on the page for the demo to work.

Some more observations:

- **I've only seen this behavior in Chrome on my Android device as well as in Chrome's DevTools when emulating a phone-sized device**, not in desktop Chrome (even with a small window)
- This doesn't happen in Firefox (neither on Android or in Firefox's DevTools' Responsive Design Mode)
- This doesn't happen if I change the header from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`
- This also doesn't happen if I remove the call `instgrm.Embeds.process();` (but then the post is not fully rendered)

What could explain this behavior? Since the fixed position element should take its dimensions from the viewport, is it possible that the viewport width is temporarily changed by Instagram's JavaScript code?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that adding `width: 100vw;` or `max-width: 100vw;` to the header (along with `box-sizing: border-box;`) seems to solve the problem, the header's width doesn't change. So looks like the header temporarily expands outside the viewport for whatever reason.